# Cocoa getting input data from DOMDocument

Tags: c#, dom, domdocument, monomac

I'm trying to get data from the DOM from a document loaded into a Cocoa WebView control but it seems like the element's value is empty. I'm using MonoMac. The code I'm using (C#) is below:

```
var document = WebBrowser.MainFrameDocument;

if (document != null)
{
    // GetAllChildren is a recursive extension function that iterates through a DomNode's
    // ChildNodes property and returns a list of all of them
    var textareaElements = document.GetAllChildren().OfType<DomHtmlElement>().Where(node => node.Name.Equals("TEXTAREA"));
    foreach (var textarea in textareaElements)
    {
        var value = textarea.Value; // this is always ""
    }
}
```

Do I need to do something to make sure the DOM reference I have to has the data entered into the webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the MonoMac implementation: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=7754

**UPDATE:** There is an active pull request that fixes this issue: https://github.com/mono/monomac/pull/109

Answer (score 0):

I rarely have to work with DOM but it seems to be the returned node is of type `Element` and the `nodeValue` will return a string only for a `Text` type.

From an `Element` you can try the `TextContent`, that does return the expected value for the bug report you mentioned.

Or you can access the `Text` node (it will be `textarea.FirstChild.Value` in your case) and that should also return the value you expect.

**UPDATE**

The original test case from the bug report did not show the real issue. A newer test case was provided and a fix is now [available](https://github.com/mono/monomac/commit/7f4a126133b2a2cc2025d92841b194c146fdc561) (on github monomac repo).

Comment: I think the bug still exists. `TextContent` is also an empty string and `FirstChild` is null. Furthermore, `OuterHTML` does not contain the updated DOM values either.

Comment: I was wondering if this bugfix has made it into a released version? Specifically, XamMac 1.2.42? Is there a way to look up that information?

Comment: @sohum yes, it should be part of 1.2.x. Beside trying the test case you can look for the new `MonoMac.WebKit.DomHtmlInputElement` type. Earlier versions did not have it (and that was part of the issue).

Comment: It appears that the <INPUT> elements are being bound correctly (their value is being promoted to the `Value` property) but that <TEXTAREA> elements don't have their value set.